# Mysql json fields - filter inside by paramter

Tags: mysql, sql, jsonfield

I have in mysql json field with the values:

```
{"a": true, "b":true, "c":false, "d":true}
```

I want to retrieve in SQL, for each row, only the keys and values that are true.

For example in the row:

```
{"a": true, "b":true, "c":false, "d":true}
```

the result will be:

```
{"a": true, "b":true, "d":true}
```

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using string (regex) functions:

```sql
SELECT id,
       val, 
       REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '(, *)?"[^"]+": *false', ''), '\\{ *, *', '\\{') without_false
FROM test
```

Using recursive CTE:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, val src, val FROM test
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id, 
                src,
                JSON_REMOVE(val, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(REPLACE(val, 'false', '"false"'), 'one', 'false')))
         FROM cte
         WHERE JSON_SEARCH(REPLACE(val, 'false', '"false"'), 'one', 'false') IS NOT NULL
         )
SELECT id, src val, val without_false
FROM cte
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(REPLACE(val, 'false', '"false"'), 'one', 'false') IS NULL
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b408d4e5fa5aae265a76bc387096834)